# Сортировка строк по возрастанию в файле Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, сортировка

Есть txt файл вида

```
01 -> (56.665744414777,-4.09513935667372) -> 150.29296875
011 -> (56.6661293622529,-4.09704076876584) -> 160.0390625
03 -> (56.6665747421354,-4.09919364584093) -> 159.1015625
04 -> (56.6668895070955,-4.10013813805868) -> 155.78125
07 -> (56.666583500041,-4.09920718895852) -> 155.88671875
11 -> (56.6661261281559,-4.09701937330206) -> 160.25390625
2 -> (56.6661261281559,-4.09701937330206) -> 153.125
20 -> (56.6657530084886,-4.09516268121721) -> 157.9140625
201 -> (56.6657530084886,-4.09516268121721) -> 159.625
22 -> (56.6654648415451,-4.09359632994024) -> 160.3125
287 -> (56.6655907727544,-4.09278733564568) -> 164.28515625
30 -> (56.6654891203157,-4.08947699433228) -> 158.9140625
301 -> (56.6656592305536,-4.08871123027875) -> 165.5390625
5 -> (56.6654648415451,-4.09359632994024) -> 165.25
6 -> (56.6656913596524,-4.08679545454817) -> 160.3515625
9 -> (56.6657085935658,-4.08308369800892) -> 152.18359375
999 -> (56.6658433607951,-4.0803983938441) -> 164.5703125
```

Необходимо отсортировать строки по первому номеру в порядке возрастания.
Сам формат файла: № точки -> Координаты  -> Высота
Пробовал функции .sort() и sorted, но как-то они у меня не сработали.

На выходе мы должны получить:

```
01 -> (56.665744414777,-4.09513935667372) -> 150.29296875
2 -> (56.6661261281559,-4.09701937330206) -> 153.125
03 -> (56.6665747421354,-4.09919364584093) -> 159.1015625
04 -> (56.6668895070955,-4.10013813805868) -> 155.78125
5 -> (56.6654648415451,-4.09359632994024) -> 165.25
6 -> (56.6656913596524,-4.08679545454817) -> 160.3515625
07 -> (56.666583500041,-4.09920718895852) -> 155.88671875
9 -> (56.6657085935658,-4.08308369800892) -> 152.18359375
011 -> (56.6661293622529,-4.09704076876584) -> 160.0390625
11 -> (56.6661261281559,-4.09701937330206) -> 160.25390625
20 -> (56.6657530084886,-4.09516268121721) -> 157.9140625
22 -> (56.6654648415451,-4.09359632994024) -> 160.3125
30 -> (56.6654891203157,-4.08947699433228) -> 158.9140625
201 -> (56.6657530084886,-4.09516268121721) -> 159.625
287 -> (56.6655907727544,-4.09278733564568) -> 164.28515625
301 -> (56.6656592305536,-4.08871123027875) -> 165.5390625
999 -> (56.6658433607951,-4.0803983938441) -> 164.5703125
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У функций `sort` и `sorted` есть параметр key, с помощью которого можно указать функцию, по значению которой нужно выполнять сортировку. В вашем случае можно разбить строку на список по пробелам, взять первый элемент, привести его к целому числу. В виде лямбда-функции будет выглядеть так:

```
lambda line: int(line.split(' -> ')[0])
```

Полный код:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines.sort(key=lambda line: int(line.split(' -> ')[0]))

print(lines)
```

Вообще удобно сначала привести все данные во внутренний формат, а потом уже обрабатывать:

```
import ast
from operator import itemgetter

def convert(parts):
    # Преобразовываем части строки в кортеж вида
    # (11, (54.37299474142492, 26.898398157209158), 160.25390625)
    return int(parts[0]), ast.literal_eval(parts[1]), float(parts[2])

with open("file.txt") as file:
    # Загружаем данные из файла в список кортежей
    data = [convert(line.rstrip().split(' -> ')) for line in file]

# Выводим данные с сортировкой по перевому элементу
print(*sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0)), sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
(1, (54.3796422611922, 26.888606417924166), 150.29296875)
(2, (54.36748347245157, 26.864477936178446), 153.125)
(3, (54.37398288398981, 26.88761961646378), 159.1015625)
(4, (54.378429567441344, 26.889896811917424), 155.78125)
(5, (54.37056927010417, 26.87919421121478), 165.25)
(6, (54.36773962341249, 26.876613423228264), 160.3515625)
(7, (54.36729043722153, 26.872438648715615), 155.88671875)
(9, (54.36747006140649, 26.867277156561613), 152.18359375)
(11, (54.374836245551705, 26.895210184156895), 160.0390625)
(11, (54.37299474142492, 26.898398157209158), 160.25390625)
(20, (54.3712879344821, 26.893919790163636), 157.9140625)
(22, (54.37299474142492, 26.89111126586795), 160.3125)
(30, (54.37568969093263, 26.88519070856273), 158.9140625)
(201, (54.37708209268749, 26.89133900217712), 159.625)
(287, (54.36944726854563, 26.879338715225458), 164.28515625)
(301, (54.37294981442392, 26.87987733632326), 165.5390625)
(999, (54.37465662136674, 26.88276171684265), 164.5703125)
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь сортировкой по ключу:

```
def by_order(str):
    return int(str.split(' -> ')[0])
x = sorted(x, key = by_order)
```

Для интеграции с вашим кодом:

```
arr = []
with open('obj/waypoints.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as wp_fle:
    filecontents = wp_fle.readlines()    
    for line in filecontents:
        x = line[:-1]
        arr.append(x)
```

Таким образом вы получите массив строк из вашего файла, чтобы работать с ним(сортировать)

Comment: Простите за глупость, но как я могу совместить этот код со своим:with open('obj/waypoints.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as wp_fle:

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ